# Изменить каждый четвёртый элемент на строку

Tags: python, строки, list

Мне нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть список элементов. Мне нужно каждый четвертый элемент сменить на 'X'. Мне удалось изменить только первый элемент, но я не знаю как изменить все, которые подпадают под каждый четвертый. Помогите: как мне изменить каждый четвертый элемент на 'X' и вывести полный список с измененными элементами? Спасибо вам большое

```
list_of_numbers_two = [22,3,5,2,8,2,-23,8,23,5]
x_items = [str(item) for item in list_of_numbers_two[::4]]
x_items[0::] = 'X'
print(x_items)
```

Comment: С генератором не знаю можно ли сделать, тебе надо отслеживать условие item[i] = 'X', где i % 4 == 0. Проще сделать через цикл for.

Comment: `arr[0::4] = 'X'*len(arr[0::4])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for index, i in enumerate(list_of_numbers_two):
    if index == 0: continue
    if index % 4 == 0:
        list_of_numbers_two[index] = "X"
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое)) Последняя просьба, могли бы вы объяснить немного этот код??

Comment: **if index == 0: continue** можно убрать, т.к. незачем

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of_numbers_two = [22,3,5,2,8,2,-23,8,23,5,22,3,5,2,8,2,-23,8,23,5]
l  = len(list_of_numbers_two) // 4
for i in range(1, len(list_of_numbers_two) + 1):
    if i % 4 == 0:
        list_of_numbers_two[i - 1] = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_numbers_two = [22,3,5,2,8,2,-23,8,23,5]
    for index, i in enumerate(list_of_numbers_two):
    #Оставляешь, если первый элемент не нужно менять на "Х"
    #if index == 0: continue
    if index % 4 == 0:
        list_of_numbers_two[index] = "X"
```

Функция enumerate() позволяет получить сразу индекс элемента + его значение.

```
# Посмотри, что выдает этот код
list_of_numbers_two = [22,3,5,2,8,2,-23,8,23,5,4,3,2]
for index, i in enumerate(list_of_numbers_two):
    print(index, i)
```

Comment: `['X' if i % 4 == 0 else item for i, item in enumerate(list_of_numbers_two , start=1)]`